# Does anyone know what one would do to participate in a cloud community?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, iaas

I've been looking at the plaintive entreaties for participation on cloud.com and eucalyptus.com

I have read much of their documentation and looked at cloud.com's videos, the introductory video on cloud.com in particular is a fine example of someone saying nothing for four minutes while reassuring you that what he's talking about is "cool".

I've played a bit of Call of Cthulhu in my time and am wary of getting involved with cults trying to invoke elder gods through bizarre rituals. When communities are so cagey, vague and inconclusive about what it is they do I have to wonder...

What the hell would one do in contributing to these communities? What benefit does contributing confer apart from being able to play buzzword bingo on your resume?

For context sake. I am asking this because an outsource developer we are using is getting involved with amazon ec2 stuff and we've been having a look at those services. So that I can understand how all this whizz-bang IaaS stuff works I'd like to poke about in one but I'm not paying to do so out of my own pocket and, frankly, no one in our office fully understands how this all works and the venture is unlikely to attract budget until someone with the company credit card "gets" it. Usually I have found experience is the best teacher but I don't know what I am supposed to be experiencing or how best to experience it.

I guess this boils down to: is there any kind of cloud service similar to ec2 I could "have a go" with for free? And if not is there anyone who can explain it without using a thesaurus of current business flavours du jour sprinkled liberally with the word "cool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's with some intrepidation that I try to answer your question (first time answerer, be kind :) ).

Your line of questioning isn't silly - it is just what I'm trying to figure out myself, what are the compelling reasons to implement cloud computing? I'm the technical writer for OpenStack, and I want to write some starter tutorials for some virtual "try it out" images we're creating.

The title question, "what to do to participate in a cloud community" really depends on the community. We're so early-on that community participation is pretty technical - get a Launchpad account, try out the code, talk to us on IRC and mailing lists. Other communities would have different participation patterns.

In summary, I think you could try OpenStack's developer preview out, get a feel for our community, and play with the cloud fabric controller (spin virtual machines up and down and so on) using VirtualBox.

So, if you want to try out OpenStack's Compute (aka Nova on Launchpad), download Virtual Box, and then get the image by [downloading from here](http://c0028699.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/nova-vm.zip). Unzip the image, then start Virtual Box. There's a readme in the zip file that has step-by-step instructions (not super air-tight, but I'm testing them). What I'm trying to learn myself is "what's a good starter tutorial for *aaS?"

Comment: The outsource company we are involved with built us some software in an ec2 instance (for no real reason than they didn't have a spare actual development server). I had a look around what they were doing and the idea appeals to us because the business I work for wants to a) save money on hardware b) attain lower maintenance costs and the killer c) manage occasional insanely high traffic spikes to a web server in a usual sea of fairly mediocre traffic. Basically whatever we do should be plug and play, fire and forget choose your quick and easy metaphor of choice...

Comment: Accepted as answer in lieu of one that I think answers the final question posed in this answer.

Comment: I'll keep working on the starter tutorials, thanks for confirming its import. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd find [10 Steps to Initiating an OpenStack Cloud Service](http://www.openstack.org/blog/2011/02/10-steps-to-initiating-an-openstack-cloud-service/) an interesting read.  It's all about how to get a major service (i.e. code contribution) accepted into OpenStack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any free Cloud providers - but EC2 isn't going to hurt you. I work with it daily in the office, billed to a corporate card, and I use it for personal projects billed to my own card.

Signup to EC2 is free, and if you already have an Amazon account as a purchaser then it's just a couple of clicks. Spinning-up a Micro or Small instance for a few hours to play with it will set you back a few pence. Leave it running and you'll venture into pounds territory - but we're talking £10 or £20 for a months' usage. Fire a Medium or Large (or larger) up, and you'll accrue charges at a higher rate, obviously. Terminate any instances and zap any storage you might have created, and the billing drops to zero.

EC2 pricing is [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think their pricing is excessive but I don't really know what to do with it once I've got it. I guess this is where we're going to end up eventually. I think this whole IaaS thing seems like a good thing in the right circumstances and I would like to contribute to something if I am able. I think whichever cloud vendor offers free "Mickey Mouse" virtual services first will have a serious competitive advantage as devs love toys.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have a solution looking for a problem. If you don't have an objective which Cloud Computing will help you achieve (regardless of provider) then you'll be wasting your time and money. And, to be honest, if you just want to experience the 'tech' involved in Cloudlike virtual machines, just start by playing with one of the free virtualisation applications that allow you to host virtual machines on a local PC (e.g. VirtualPC, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc).

Comment: Possibly so. The problem is I don't really even know what I'm looking at... hence the silly questions.

Comment: I wouldn't describe the question as 'silly', but perhaps as pre-emptive; play with the desktop-based virtualisation facilities until you have a firm grasp of the differences (both subtle and gross) between physical and virtual environments. Then if you have the time dip a toe in the water with EC2 (or similar) for a cheap introduction to Cloud-based virtualisation. Then leave it alone until someone approaches you with a problem that you can solve with [local|cloud] virtual machines. Then get stuck in.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options. However in my opinion, the most useful and easy options would be to go along with OpenStack. Read about it. Visit devstack.org, and OpenStack official website and install it on your system. Observe it and figure out how it works. Once you are comfortable with its working and code structure, go to launchpad and pick problems you think you can solve it then learn git( if you don't know already) then propose your solution. Get in touch with IRC channel associated with the project you wish to work upon. And with time you will start enjoying it.